# How to use Near By search in Google Map API? - ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I am trying to implement Nearby Search from Google Map API in asp .NET but unable to find a solution for it. How can I implement/use this feature of Google Map API?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in the Places library for the `textSearch` method.

[Here is the API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests)

Comment: How to implement it in asp.net project?

Comment: There is a code example in the link I sent showing exactly how to use it @rikky

Comment: @rikky, are you trying to do this server side or client side? The javascript example in the API should work in your client side no problem.

Comment: I am trying to do this on server side.

Comment: Yes. I am using C#. currently i am using by http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24468/Google-Maps-Control-for-ASP-NET-Part-1   , but i can't find text search in this example. can u tell me how to implement text search in this example.